# How do I make selenium see the network requests made by a web browser?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I have a dotnet Selenium web driver app.

When I'm testing the page one of the things I need to confirm is that a flash object on the page has pulled correct content from a content store on my site. (i.e. the flash object **should** be loading content from /stuff/info.txt and including that content within the animation.)

As a human looking at this I can use the chrome network tab and see that /stuff/info.txt has been accessed.

How can I make Selenium execute a similar watch and see the network requests made by a web browser?

Answer (score 2):

I did not wrote this, neither tested it however someone did it here: http://www.softwareishard.com/blog/firebug/automate-page-load-performance-testing-with-firebug-and-selenium/

Basically all the requests are exported via netexport and firebug plugins inside a HAR (Http ARchive file)

Please give us your feedback if you give it a try!

Cheers !

Comment: Sounds very interesting. I have to try it. But for the question, is it possible to get the content of remote ajax data from an url?

Comment: Using netexport is the only way you can access the list of ajax request that has been made. Selenium won't allow you to retrieve directly this kind of information.

Comment: I has some spare time to dig more on this topic. And netexport / firebug solution is not the only one. In fact a simpler one is to use browserMob: http://assertselenium.com/2012/11/02/performance-data-collection-using-browsermob-proxy-and-selenium/

Comment: Thats another interesting link. Thanks for that. The question is actually related to verifying the remote calls are fetching correct data or not.. so I dont think it can be done by any means.

Comment: To be completly sure, I checked with another perspective. The jsonWireProtocol on which selenium relies does allow it: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol. As a workaround you could implement it with javascript coding. The object used to export the har data are available. This javascript code could then be executed through selenium.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to automate the process which the developer tools of browsers does. Something like firebug but for verification using Code.

I don't believe Selenium has such features. For now, you will not be able to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I'm trying to do. I think there might be a solution hidden in monkeying with proxies along the lines of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18815542/prevent-external-content-to-be-loaded-in-selenium-webdriver-test but I'm not sure.