# How to reduce the execution speed of selenium

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

My application is using Boot Strap framework. All the fields of the application get saved on tab-out operation(When focus is moved out of the field).

**code:**

```
driver.findElement(By.id("author")).sendkeys("xyz");  
driver.findElement(By.xpath("url")).sendkeys("aaa");
```

**Problem:**
When focus moves from the field `author` an ajax request is sent and it takes minimum of 2-3s to respond back. In between the latency time my next lines of code is executed i.e. (here `url` field and so on). Exact issue is after the server response the application erased all the field values which were entered before the response receive.

I thought the solution would be to reduce the execution speed. But I am aware in web driver we don't have an option `setspeed` like in RC.

I don't think the **Implicit** and **Explicit** will help here. Because the element will be present in the DOM.

Is any other workaround or possible solution to overcome this? TIA.

Comment: You say you have to wait before entering the data in the next field but how would a user using this application *know* that they have to wait before typing into the other fields?

Comment: @Louis: In production the response is very fast and the user doesn't face any problem. But regression suite has to be run on QA box. There I am facing problem because of the response latency time.

Comment: @Manigandan In that case you should mirror your production box. That's the whole point of testing. Mirror the production as much as possible

Comment: Check [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18827260/1315120) about using a proxy.

Comment: Are you suggesting that the DOM will not by modified by the javascript in any way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use implicit or explicit wait, but implicit wait will be applicable for the life of the WebDriver object instance (unless you change it again), so better you can go with explicit wait or fluent wait.

Explicit wait

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);  
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("foo")));
```

Fluent Wait

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
    .withTimeout(30, SECONDS)
    .pollingEvery(5, SECONDS)
    .ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

     WebElement foo = wait.until(new Function<WebDriver, WebElement>() 
     {
        public WebElement apply(WebDriver driver) {
        return driver.findElement(By.id("foo"));
     }
});
```

Personally I prefer Explicit/Fluent wait over implicit wait. 
You can check this really nice answer about comparison of different waits https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/12866/how-fluentwait-is-different-from-webdriverwait

Answer (score 0):

Other approach is capturing the network traffic. Then you will able to know when the ajax request was sent and catch the response. So your logic will be driven by appropriated ajax request/response. Please see Java example [here](http://blog.eviltester.com/2010/05/a-selenium-capturenetworktraffic-example-in-java.html).

Comment: The link you provided is about `selenium` (version 1), but the question is tagged as `selenium-webdriver` or version 2 if you prefer that wording

Comment: Other than that, a proxy can be used to achieve this, I have answered about setting up a proxy [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18827260/1315120).

Comment: Agree. There are many ways to implement this capturing, I just wanted to illustrate the idea,